# How to load property files outside of war file when using spring boot loader WarLauncher?

Tags: java, classpath, manifest, war, spring-boot

I have created an executable war file by specifying WarLauncher (part of spring boot loader) as my start up class. It works fine when all configuration files (properties, spring context, etc) are part of my resources folder. I expect consumer of my war requiring control on the property file. Hence it is required to be loaded outside of war file. I am expecting the properties file in a config folder (deployed side by side with the war file). I have tried to add appropriate classpath entries to the manifest by making use of maven plugin but it did not worked.

The following is how relevant section of my maven POM file looks like:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.3</version>
   <configuration>
      <archive>
         <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <mainClass>org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher</mainClass>
         </manifest>
         <manifestEntries>
            <Start-Class><<myclass_dont_worry_about_this>></Start-Class>
            <Class-Path>config/</Class-Path>
         </manifestEntries>
      </archive>
      <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I am using Spring ClassPathResource() for loading the property file. The following shows the code snippet for the same:

```
 InputStream stream = new ClassPathResource(classPathConfigFilePath).getInputStream();
 Proerties properties = new Properties();
 properties.load(stream);
```

At runtime, it is not able to locate the property file resulting in FileNotFoundException.

Thanks.

Comment: An `application.properties` next to the artifact will be picked up automatically. YOu shouldn't need to load it yourself as spring-boot will automatically add it for you.

Comment: I changed the code for application.properties. I created application.properties along side my war file. On execution it is still giving FileNotFoundException.

Comment: As mentioned spring-boot already loads that file so you don't need to load it... WHy do you want to load it yourself? Also the fact that it is alongside your artifact makes it that it isn't on the classpath but on the filesystem. So loading it with a `ClassPathResource` isn't going to work... Also see http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/spring-boot/README.html

Comment: Hmmm... but, how do I access the values in that properties file?

Comment: By using placeholders in a `@Value` annotation or by pulling them out of the `Environment`, the latter you can simply inject by adding a field of the type `Environment` to your configuration and annotate it with `@Autowired`. But in general using @Value is easier.

Comment: See my extended answer.

Comment: I don't think this problem has anything to do with the WarLauncher. You don't reveal the value of "classPathConfigFilePath" but are you perhaps trying to load a classpath resource from the default package? The default package exists in many locations (e.g. jar files) in your archive, so you have to do a bit more work to load it . You could, for instance, use a `ResourcePatternResolver` in Spring and load it from "classpath*:...".

Comment: @DaveSyer: classPathConfigFilePath = "dbconnection.properties". The file dbconnection.properties is in config folder. Config folder is at the same level as my war file.

Comment: So what makes you think it is on the classpath? I'm confused.

Comment: <manifestEntries>
            <Start-Class><<myclass_dont_worry_about_this>></Start-Class>
            <Class-Path>config/</Class-Path>
         </manifestEntries>

Answer (score 5):

Spring-Boot by default searches the following locations for an `application.properties` file

1. classpath root
2. current directory
3. classpath `/config` package
4. `/config` subdirectory of the current directory

All those files, when available are loaded in that order which means properties from 1 can be overriden by 2,3,4. All the loaded properties are available as part of the `Environment` and as such can be used in placeholders for configuration.

As an addition to the loading rules above also [profile](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html#new-in-3.1-bean-definition-profiles) specific files can be loaded. For a given profile it will also try to load an `application-{profile}.properties`. For that specific file the loading rules as mentioned above are also taken into account.

All loaded properties are available through the `Environment` which means that are availabe through springs [unified property management](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/). One can either use the `Environment` directly to retrieve configuration parameters or use placeholders with the `@Value` annotation for configuration

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfigClass {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public DataSource dataSource() {
        SimpleDriverDataSource ds = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        ds.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
        ds.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
        ds.setDriverClass(Driver.class);
        ds.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        return ds;
    }
}
```

Or with `@Value`

```
 @Configuration
public class SomeConfigClass {

    @Value("${jdbc.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${jdbc.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${jdbc.url}")
    private String url


    public DataSource dataSource() {
        SimpleDriverDataSource ds = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        ds.setUsername(username);
        ds.setPassword(password);
        ds.setDriverClass(Driver.class);
        ds.setUrl(url);
        return ds;
    }
}
```

Links

1. Spring boot [READ-ME](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/spring-boot/README.html)
2. Spring Framework Profile [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html#new-in-3.1-bean-definition-profiles)
3. Spring Property Managed [blog](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/)
4. Spring Boot Loader [READ-ME](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-loader/README.html)

Comment: I am not using Spring boot as such but only the WarLauncher of the Spring boot loader. Does your solution work in that case?

Comment: My war file is dependent (not compile time but at run-time) on Spring boot loader component. The war file also depends on X (jar file) component which contains the property file loading logic. Hope, I provided the required context.

Comment: You are using spring-boot war-launcher. Which in turn uses a `SpringApplication` which in turn has the support for loading properties. I strongly suggest you read the, currently sparse, documentation available on Spring boot. In short use what is given to you instead of trying to reinvent the wheel and workaround the framework.